# Asp.net 4 Gridview Gridview Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some validation controls on my gridview and would like them to anly be active when I try to save/update data in a gridview row and not when cancelling using the cancel button. How can I implement this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set **CausesValidation="False"** for the Cancel Button.

**Control.CausesValidation Property**

If the CausesValidation property is set to false, the Validating and Validated events are suppressed.

Also, specify **"ValidationGroup"** for your controls:

Validation groups allow you to organize validation controls on a page as a set. Each validation group can perform validation independently from other validation groups on the page.

You create a validation group by setting the ValidationGroup property to the same name (a string) for all the controls you want to group. You can assign any name to a validation group, but you must use the same name for all members of the group.

During postback, the Page class's IsValid property is set based only on the validation controls in the current validation group.

**Reference Links:**

[Control.CausesValidation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx)

[Specifying Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)